# Is there a way to use installations to prevent users from creating multiple accounts from one device?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, installation

I have a Parse app that requires users to create accounts. For the sake of user integrity, I do not want them to be able to create more than one account. I understand that people will always find a way around the system, but is it possible to somehow check if an account is already associated with the user's device when they are signing up?

```
func checkDevice {
      if /*Installation already exists*/ {
            displayAlert("Could not sign up. Please contact support.")
      } else {
            signUp()
      }
}
```

Comment: the simple answer is no, of course not.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a real problem I faced myself. Since, I felt like the importance of fixing that was considerably minimal, I saved a bit of effort. The answer is yes, but its not worth the effort in most cases.

### Android

The major part of the issue is getting a unique ID from a device. Back in the early days, we could have used the device IMEI number, since all of them were phones. Now, we have from watches to tablets, one possible ID that I personally feel we can rely upon is, the [Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID). But even this ID could be reset, if the user is smart enough to wipe the entire OS. Take a look at [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) and figure out which UUID you would like to use. Say for example `ANDROID_ID` can be retrieved like this.

```
String uuid = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Once you settle down, the next task is to associate this installation with the actual user.

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.put("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
installation.put("uuid", uuid);
installation.saveInBackground();
```

---

### iOS

For iOS as well, you don't get an absolutely reliable UUID. The possible option is to make use of `identifierForVendor`.

```
let uuid = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString;
let user = PFUser.currentUser();
let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation();
installation["uuid"] = uuid;
installation["user"] = user;
installation.saveInBackground();
```

And once this is done, what you can do is query the installation object, and make sure the device has not been used by any other users.